# does the number returned by send() in C include the null terminator?

Tags: c, sockets, send

I wrote this code to write to a socket (the `Server` struct contains a `socketfd` field)

```
void writeToSocket(Server *server, const char *message) {
    size_t len = strlen(message);
    int bytesWritten = 0;
    while (true) {
        bytesWritten += send(server->socketfd, message + bytesWritten, len, 0);
        if (bytesWritten-len-1 == 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

This code might have several problems - I'm a newb at this. Feel free to raise any red flags you may see. My main concern is that the loop may not terminate.

For example: the message is `hello` (aka `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, `\0`), then `strlen(message)` would be 5, but if `send` includes the `\0`, then `bytesWritten` would probably be 6. But if not it would be 5, in which case `if (bytesWritten-len-1 == 0)` is wrong. Which is correct?

Comment: Err... *you* tell `send` how many bytes you want to send!

Comment: Include the null terminator in your send-size, and if send() returns your send-size you passed it, then *yes* (just like the char before it, and before that, etc...). (and +1 Kerrek =P)

Comment: And `send` sends all kinds of bytes, it doesn't treat 0 bytes specially.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the terminator regardless. send a 32 bit (or 16 bit) length preamble in network byte order using [`htonl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) (for 32bit) or [`htons()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) (for 16bit), then send the char data. at least then you know how much you're supposed to be receiving. When you receive the length as the first bytes on the other end, reverse the byte reordering call (`ntohl()` or `ntohs()` respectively. Note: They're not standard lib (they're POSIX-1.2001) so setup your config accordingly.

Comment: Your code has plenty of other problems with it you need to address.

Answer (score 3):

`send(3)` sends the given number of *bytes*; it couldn't care less if what you send is a string, an array of integers, or a random `struct`. If you don't include the ending `'\0'`, it isn't included.